# Angular 12: Firebase modulesnot correctly provided (?)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

First time using Firebase so I don't know what's going on. I did not modify the configuration got using `ng add @angular/fire`, so what I have in my `AppModule` is:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideDatabase(() => getDatabase()),
    provideFunctions(() => getFunctions()),
    provideMessaging(() => getMessaging()),
    provideRemoteConfig(() => getRemoteConfig()),
    provideStorage(() => getStorage()),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In a different module, using lazy loading, I call method `signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)`, but I get the following error in console:

```
Either AngularFireModule has not been provided in your AppModule (this can be done manually or implictly using
provideFirebaseApp) or you're calling an AngularFire method outside of an NgModule (which is not supported).
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://fireship.io/snippets/install-angularfire/)?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara same thing

Comment: Try to add `AngularFireModule` to your providers, and change the initializer to `AngularFireModule.initializeApp(youConfig)`. Check if that works please. Those are imported by `import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';`

Comment: doesn't work either

Comment: Im having exactly the same issue i cannot find any documentation or issues on this, the compat variant works, but has ios issues that can only be solved by not using the compat version :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok i found the solution for this problem.

It appears that you need to inject the auth instance of angularfire in your service.

```html
import {Auth, sendPasswordResetEmail, signOut} from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
@Injectable()
export class FirebaseAuthService {

    constructor(..., private auth: Auth,) {
    }
    
     getFirebaseUser(): any {
        return this.auth.currentUser;
    }

    logout() {
        signOut(this.auth);
    }
    
    resetPassword(email: string) {
        return sendPasswordResetEmail(this.auth, email);
    }

    if (this.credentialsForm.valid) {
            signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.auth,this.credentialsForm.controls.email.value,
                this.credentialsForm.controls.password.value).then(result => { ... }
                }
}
```

after using this instance, it worked like a charm.